# In SVN, how do I revert ONE file back to a certain revision?

Tags: svn

Just one file, not the entire directory. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to revert only the file existing in your working copy or do you want to make the change visible to all other developers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Updating to an old revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491520/in-svn-how-do-i-revert-one-file-back-to-a-certain-revision/2491549#2491549) is rarely going to be what you want, because this will not allow you to make changes based on that old revision — SVN will complain about the file being out of date.

What you probably want to do is a [reverse merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo).  This will make the old revision the new HEAD revision.

```
# roll back to revision 200, making it the new HEAD
svn merge -r HEAD:200 theone.file
svn commit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
svn up -r200 theone.file
```

Comment: This is updating to an old revision. It doesn't change the HEAD version.

Comment: Oh, indeed. But since it was accepted, it apparently solved the problem. I'll just leave this here for reference and refer to the other answers for the *real* answer.